# App crashes when using AHAlertView project

Tags: objective-c, custom-controls

I'm trying to display a custom UIAlertView and I'm using AHAlertView:

https://github.com/warrenm/AHAlertView

I added both AHAlertView.m and .h to my project and add the following to the viewDidLoad method:

```
        NSString *title = @"Alert View Title";
    NSString *message = @"This is a message that might prompt you to do something.";

    AHAlertView *alert = [[AHAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message];
    __weak AHAlertView *weakAlert = alert;
    [alert setCancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" block:^{
        weakAlert.dismissalStyle = AHAlertViewDismissalStyleTumble;
    }];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK" block:^{
        weakAlert.dismissalStyle = AHAlertViewDismissalStyleZoomDown;
    }];
    [alert show];
```

The problem is when I'm tapping either one of the buttons, the app crashes with:
"Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

I don't know what I did wrong, I looked at the sample project and this is the way the alert is being used.
How can I implement it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate *-fno-objc-arc* option ? If you did, deactivate it, AHAlertView support ARC